# Este error aparece : FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE:NET: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /C:assets/css.main.css.css1

Tags: html, css, html5

no puedo enviar mi CSS hacia mi pagina web

¿que estoy haciendo mal?

---

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <header>
        <h1>Las Mejores pizzas de mi Ciudad</h1>
      </header>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Ubicación</th>
          <th>Calificación</th>
          <th>Acciones</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Sensei</td>
            <td>Av Central 500</td>
            <td><i class="fas fa-star-of-david"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star-of-david"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-star-of-david"></i>
            </td>
              <a href="./restaurantes/sensei.html">Ver más  </a>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Pepe's Pizza</td>
            <td>Av Central 500</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>La Calabaza</td>
          <td>Av Central 500</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Este es mi documento Html

Este es mi documento CSS

```
.container{
  background: #642B73;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #C6426E, #642B73);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #C6426E , #642B73);
}
```

Comment: el "Necesito que busquen el error" no es lo mismo que "pueden ayudarme a resolver este problema", es un foro de ayuda, no de soporte. hay que aprender a solicitar ayuda, y viendo tu código incompleto, aunque superes el error que este contiene, nada nos garantiza que en el resto del código no tengas los mismos errores.

Comment: Para mí se ve bien, así que voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es un problema que no se puede reproducir

Answer (score 3):

falta el punto y coma (;)
background: #642B73;

Comment: lo acabo de hacer y sigue sin aparecerme el fondo en la página web

Comment: El error es que no encuentra el .CSS.